# Error in installing cardova in Mac

Tags: node.js, cordova

```
CFL2-WS-06:~ aamirkhan$ npm install -g cordova ios-deploy 
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/aamirkhan/.npm/ios-deploy/1.3.2/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/aamirkhan/.npm/cordova/4.2.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/aamirkhan/Desktop/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

As the answer got 5 upvotes, I would like to recommend NOT using sudo when installing cordova or other NPM packages, and change the node install to not require sudo.

There are a few alternatives:

1. Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)
2. Install node using homebrew
3. Fix npm permissions https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

OLD ANSWER:

you have no permissions to write, use the `sudo` command

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ios-deploy
```

then enter your password